# .net core v3 beta on azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

Is it possible at this time (end of February, 2019) to deploy a .net core v3 beta backend to azure?  I'd like to update some of my play stuff to .net core v3, but I only use it via azure  I'm specifically looking at an azure web app that is currently running windows.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the runtime as an App Service extension. Look for "ASP.NET Core 3.0 (x86/x64) Runtime"